# formatted input using scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

I need to take a string as input, discard eveything that is not a space, hyphen or numbers. In other words I only want positive and negative integer numbers to be read in.
I'm not deadset on using scanf but I would prefer it.

What I've tried so far is:

```
char buffer[200];

scanf("%[0-9 ' ']*%c", buffer); /*this works perfectly, except the hyphen part*/
scanf("%[0-9 - ' ']%*c", buffer); /*no change*/
scanf("%[0-9 '-' ' ']%*c", buffer); /*still no change*/
```

Obviously only tried one of them at a time.

Grateful for any insight or help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised this works for you:

```
scanf("%[0-9 ' ']*%c", buffer);
                 ^--- There's a typo, here. The * should probably be after the %.
```

Onto more pressing matters... In the C11 standard, at section §7.21.6.2p12, under the `[` conversion specifier there are some sentences that explain:

> If a - character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the
>   second where the first character is a ^, nor the last character, the
>   behavior is implementation-defined.

As a result, I would suggest two things:

1. You can't rely on `0-9` portably representing the range of characters `0123456789` within your scanset. You're better off explicitly stating `0123456789`.
2. Your implementation isn't interpreting `-` as you'd like it to.

I suggest something like this:

```
assert(scanf("%[- 0123456789]%*c", buffer) == 1);
```

You *need* to check the return value. If `scanf` returns 0, or `EOF`, then you can't expect anything well-defined by using `buffer`. I put the `-` at the start of the scanset, so that it's well defined, and expanded your `0-9` to `0123456789` as mentioned earlier.

I hope that helps :)